# running war from command line without maven jetty

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am trying to put a piece of open source software in a docker container (https://github.com/att/XACML) but in this container I can not use maven. The documentation for running this service says to use mvn jetty, which does work fine, but in order to get this in a container I don't want to include a build step (maven).

Instead, I'd like a way to compile the a war, so I can copy just the war into the container and execute it from there.

I have tried many attempts to get the war running without maven jetty but none of them work.

1. java -jar /path/to/jar
   no main manifest attribute error. There is no main class, it extends an HttpServlet
2. using jetty-runner
   when I launch the war with jetty-runner through the command line I do not get any errors, but it boots up to a page showing the directory of files, and not the actual project.
3. Making an 'uber-jar' to package all deps
   same issue as 1, get a no main manifest issue.

I can include more code if that would be helpful (pom files etc), but I don't want to add too much if it is unneeded. I am super unfamiliar with how java projects are packaged and deployed, so I am having a difficult time figuring out what needs to be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal `Dockerfile` to work with your webapp / war file is ...

```
FROM jetty:9.4.18
ADD ROOT.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/
```

This uses the official jetty docker image at
https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty

Managed at
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.docker

> The name `ROOT.war` is special, and will deploy your webapp in the "root" context path of `"/"`

### Building Image

If you build it like this ...

```sh
$ docker build -t stackoverflow/jetty:latest .
```

### Running Image

**Interactively (so you can the logs)**

```sh
$ docker run --interactive --tty --rm --publish 80:8080 stackoverflow/jetty:latest
```

**As Daemon**

```
$ docker run --detach --publish 80:8080 stackoverflow/jetty:latest
```

The server will be available on port 80 of the machine you ran the `docker run` command on.

### Configuring Jetty Base

If you need to configure the jetty image you can use any of the standard `start.jar` commands.

Example:

```
FROM jetty:9.4.18
WORKDIR $JETTY_BASE
RUN java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=jsp
ADD ROOT.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/
```

## How This Works Without Maven

See the official image details ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.docker/blob/master/9.4-jdk11/Dockerfile

The key commands are ...

```
WORKDIR $JETTY_BASE
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["java","-jar","/usr/local/jetty/start.jar"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting issues that seem specific to the war that did not show up when running with maven. Does maven package the war any differently?